# Extension method or subclass to create a System.Drawing.Color based on another color and an alpha?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, system.drawing.color

I want to create colors in C# (not XAML) using one of the following idioms:

```
Color transparentblue = TransparentColor(Brushes.Blue, 0.5); // 0.5 => 128
Color transparentblue = Brushes.Blue.SetAlpha(0.5);  // again, 0.5 => 128
```

I want to get rid of the `Color.FromArgb()` syntax, which is not designer friendly at all. I also got it working with a static method inside a static class, but the writing got a bit heavy:

```
public static class ColorGenerators {        
    public static Color GetTransparentColor (Color color, double opacity) {
        byte op = (byte)(opacity*255);

        return Color.FromArgb(op, color.R, color.G, color.B);
    }
}

// To be used as
var transparentblue = ColorGenerators.GetTransparentColor(Color.Blue, 0.5);
```

I still would prefer the Extension Method approach, and it seems to me that soon our company would benefit from methods similar to the ones described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/780759/401828), so I wonder what they would look like (given that Color is a struct, not a class).

Comment: Well yes, you can easily write an extension method like that (although I'd suggest calling it WithAlpha rather than SetAlpha). What have you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: @JonSkeet ha, exactly what I ended up calling it in my answer

Comment: @JonSkeet what went wrong is that I don't know where to start :P Totally new to extension methods...

Comment: @heltonbiker: Okay, so did you try searching for them on MSDN first? My first hit was http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
public static class ColorExtensions
{        
    public static Color WithAlpha(this Color color, double opacity) 
    {
        byte op = (byte)(opacity*255);
        return Color.FromArgb(op, color.R, color.G, color.B);
    }
}
```

The key is the `this` keyword in the first parameter. That (as well as being a `static` method in a `static` class) indicates to the compiler that this is an extension method.

```
Color transparentblue = Color.Blue.WithAlpha(0.5);
```

**Further Reading**

- [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: "The key is the this keyword in the first parameter. That (as well as being a static method in a static class) indicates to the compiler that this is an extension method." That was scattered through the docs (and I am quite burnt out lately... :oP ). Thanks!!